# Which class should be used to create proxy server for a web browser in C#.net

Tags: c#, proxy

I am trying to create a Web Browser. I want to give it a functionality like Internet Explorer have i.e Tools -> Internet Options-> Connections -> Lan Settings -> Proxy server.
This proxy server takes a address and port number . Can anyone know that which class should be  used for this purpose in C#.net.
I have read alot for proxy servers but i only got one answer" a proxy server is a server that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from other servers"

I am confused in the following point:-

1. According to definition , a proxy server is a server that provide response to the request coming to a website. So how can a browser provide a proxy server setting?
2. Is proxy server  of browser and proxy server created for website different?

Answer (score 0):

A proxy server and a web browser are entirely different things.

A proxy server takes a request, often an http request, from a client (often a web browser) and fulfills that request by turning around and fetching the resource that was requested.  It is a "man in the middle" so to speak.  It sits between the client and the real resource.  Proxy servers are often used in order to meet network security requirements, control access to outside resources (think Net Nanny), or to cache frequently requested content.

A web browser, on the other hand, retrieves resources from a web server (typically over http or https) and renders whatever content the server returns.

If you wish to create a proxy server, have a look at

http://times.imkrisna.com/2011/08/simple-http-proxy-server-c-source-code/

If you wish to create a web browser from scratch, that is a huge undertaking.  You will not find a single class that does that for you.